# Autosys job returns and error code 122

Tags: vbscript, autosys

Autosys returns and error code 122, even though the job hosted on the Autosys server have executed successfully. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Need more information. What is the autorep -J <jobname> -d output? Event Code 122, is where the event process schedules a check run window event. Does the job have a run window?

Answer (score 3):

For each error code, there is a unique description for it.

For Error code 122: the description is "Cannot open std_out_file (unix error)".